# Почему при переключении веток остаются внесенные изменения?

Tags: git, git-branch

Допустим есть **master**, где есть какие-то незакоммиченные файлы.

Создаю новую ветку **new_branch**, переключаюсь на неё, делаю в ней какие-то изменения.

Переключаюсь обратно на **master** и вижу те же самые изменения в **master**

Что-то не пойму, так и должно быть?

Ветка **master** должна видеть только свои изменения, насколько я понял...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В тот момент, когда Вы переключаетесь на другую ветку, но не закоммитились (вообще то это очень плохая практика, так не нужно делать), то будет слития (merge) изменений. Соотвественно, когда ещё и в новой ветке сделаете изменения и снова переключитесь, то теперь суммарные изменения будут в master.

Хорошая практика говорит, что перед тем, как переключиться на другую ветку, нужно закомитить изменения, спрятать или удалить.

Кстати, спрятать изменения - очень хорошая штука. Вначале делаете `git stash`. git запоминает Ваши изменения в специальном "кармане" и удаляет их из кода. Потом можно переключиться на другую ветку, поработать, закомитить и вернуться в назад. И теперь нужно достать изменения с кармана с помощью `git stash pop`. Карман работает как стек и туда можно вложить много изменений.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что на тот момент, когда вы переключились обратно на `master`, вы ещё не сделали ни одного коммита в `new_branch`. Для Git'a обе ветки совершенно одинаковы, они указывают на один и тот же коммит. При переключении веток не может произойти конфликт, потому что вообще нечего переключать. Поэтому все ваши изменения остаются нетронутыми.

Вот этот пример можно скопировать целиком в консоль и посмотреть на результаты.

```
git init;
echo 'a'>a;
cat a;
git add a;
git commit -m'a';
git checkout -b new_branch;
echo 'b'>a;
cat a;
git checkout master;
cat a;
```

А вот если бы вы сделали из них коммит, тогда ветки бы разошлись и указывали на разные коммиты. Тогда при переключении на `master` в рабочей области было бы содержимое последнего коммита `master`.

Почти то же самое, но теперь мы сделаем коммит в новой ветке.

```
git init;
echo 'a'>a;
cat a;
git add a;
git commit -m'a';
git checkout -b new_branch;
echo 'b'>a;
cat a;
git add a;
git commit -m'saved a in new_branch'
git checkout master;
cat a;
```

Точно также вы можете сначала внести изменения, а потом создать ветку, переключиться на нее и сохранить эти изменения. Например, вы что-то изменили с момента последнего коммита, хотите оставить это как альтернативный путь решения и начать заново. Аналогичный пример:

```
git init;
echo 'a'>a;
cat a;
git add a;
git commit -m'a';
echo 'b'>a;
cat a;
git checkout -b new_branch;
git add a;
git commit -m'saved a in new_branch'
git checkout master;
cat a;
```