# Почему возможен переход на другую ветку при незафиксированных изменениях?

Tags: git, git-branch

Похожая ситуация. Никак не разобраться...

Из книги git book:

> если в вашем рабочем каталоге или
>   индексе имеются незафиксированные
>   изменения, которые конфликтуют с
>   веткой, на которую вы переходите, Git
>   не позволит переключить ветки.

Вопрос: почему `$ git checkout working_branch` с легкостью это позволил?

> git предполагает, что возможно вы
>   хотите его закоммитить в другой ветке

закоммитил. От этого не легче: все три бранча работают как один (по сути потеряны все преимущества работы с бранчами в гите).

Что происходит, никак не понять. Возможно, мое следующее уточнение прояснит ситуацию. До этого, чуть ранее, я сделал pull в мастере, затем в develop сделал merge с мастером, затем в рабочем бранче (crm633) сделал merge c develop (то есть я по сути слил обновления с самой рутовой ветки до своей текущей рабочей). После этого все три бранча стали работать как один. Что я делаю не так? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: преобразуйте в вопрос, а то как то ответом оно не смотрится.

Comment: @kuramp, преобразовал в вопрос и чуть-чуть изменил, если что не так - отредактируйте.

Comment: не очень понятно, вы же все ветки привели к одному коммиту. вот смотрите. http://pastebin.com/2gPr7afa и http://pastebin.com/gxfJjaaB всё работает как ожидалось.

Comment: что имеете ввиду, говоря

> После этого все три бранча стали работать как один.

?

Comment: Задайте вопрос в формате набора команд, которые приводят к непонятному для вас поведения, начиная с пустого репозитория (`git init`), как у eicto. А то сложно угадать, что вас смущает...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему при переключении веток остаются внесенные изменения?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/327240/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > если в вашем рабочем каталоге или индексе имеются незафиксированные изменения, которые конфликтуют с веткой, на которую вы переходите, Git не позволит переключить ветки.
>
> Вопрос: почему $ git checkout working_branch с легкостью это позволил?

Вероятно потому, что конфликтов не было. Либо вы зафиксировали конфликтные изменения (`add`, `commit`). Других вариантов быть не может.

> После этого все три бранча стали работать как один.

Ветка в Git – это просто скользящий указатель на коммит. После слияния веток все три указывают на один и тот же коммит. Пока ни в одну ветку не добавлены новые коммиты, они так и будут на него указывать. В отношении `git checkout branchname` они действительно работают одинаково — но и только. Как только вы сделаете новый коммит, на него переместится указатель именно той ветки, в которой вы в данный момент находитесь.

То же самое относится к `rebase`, `filter-branch` и другим комаднам, меняющим историю Git. Та ветка, в которой вы находитесь, изменится. Остальные никак не будут затронуты.

Причина в том, что [коммит — это неизменяемый объект](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/662466/181472). Любое действие, которое «меняет» коммит, на самом деле создает новый. При этом старый продолжает существовать, и все указатели, которые указывали на него (например, ветка или метка (tag)), продолжат указывать именно на него.