# Дублирование файлов в ветках

Tags: git, echo, touch

При создании файла/директории в локальном репозитории git, файл копируется во все ветки, а не в ту в которой создается (через консоль и редактор). Как этого избежать?

Comment: в смысле вы создали файл, не добавили его в реп и при переключении веток он остается ? это так и задумано, сделайте коммит с этим файлом в нужной ветке.

Comment: Спасибо zb, разобрался

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вообще, создаёте вы файлы/каталоги не в репозитории/хранилище, а в рабочем каталоге (*working directory/tree*).

в хранилище файлы (точнее, их содержимое) «попадают» только после команды `git commit`.

при переключении между ветками/коммитами программа *git* «вычисляет», какие изменения следует внести в рабочий каталог:

- файлы/каталоги, которые есть в текущей ветке/коммите, но отсутствуют в той, на которую переключаетесь, удаляются;
- файлы/каталоги, которых нет в текущей ветке/коммите, но которые присутствуют в той, на которую переключаетесь, извлекаются из содержимого хранилища;
- аналогично извлекается и содержимое файлов, которое отличается: в текущей ветке/коммите — одно, в той, на которую переключаетесь — другое.

все же остальные файлы/каталоги при переключении между ветками/коммитами вообще никак не будут затронуты.

это относится и к тем файлам/каталогам, которых нет ни в текущей ветке/коммите, ни в той, на которую переключаетесь.

---

> Как этого избежать?

пока вы не сохранили эти файлы/каталоги внутри хранилища, программа *git*, по крайней мере, выполняя команду *checkout*, не будет «касаться» таких «неотслеживаемых» файлов/каталогов внутри рабочего каталога.

так что краткий ответ: **никак не избежать**. так задумано.

Comment: Доходчиво. Благодарю.

Comment: Есть более ранний вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/327240/181472, но у вас здесь ответ подробнее. Сомневаюсь, в какую сторону дубликатить.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а какая, в общем, разница? на оба вопроса даны вполне исчерпывающие ответы. по-моему, можно закрывать (как дубль) любой из них. а с перекрёстной ссылкой и релевантностью пусть поисковики разбираются.