# Изменения внесённые на одной из веток проекта сразу переносятся на все другие ветки

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

[image: этот же пакет создаётся в ветке мастер (и в остальных) тоже и с кодом][image: из ветки мастер создал ветку S04-T05, на ней создал пакет s04 и класс Task05]При работе с проектом в `intellij idea`, после внесения каких либо изменений (изменение текста кода или создание файла) эти изменения сразу передаются и на другие ветки. Если удалить их (эти изменения) на любой из веток, они так же удалятся отовсюду. Раньше такого не было и изменения добавленные на ветке только там и хранились, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: подозреваю, что просто это измения, которые не закоммитили. Но idea она такая, умеет делать autostash (то есть прятать изменения при переходе между ветками). Но либо они пошли на путь праведный (во что я мало верю), толи Антон начал переключать ветки самостоятельно, толи в настройках полазил и все поплыло.

Comment: Как удалось - не знаю. 
В настройках ничего не менял, но ветки переключаю да, но что в этом такого если изменения на них не вношу, а только посмотреть передалось ли снова изменение с новой ветки на все остальные

Comment: Поведение аналогично такому, что изменения есть в рабочей копии, но их нет в индексе (не была вызвана команда `git commit` или произведены аналогичные ей действия). Проверить можно выполнив команду `git status`.

Comment: @Антон, будьте добры, понимаю, что это был год назад, но если вы нашли решение данной проблемы, то не могли вы подсказать решение. Заранее огромное спасибо. Целый день мучаюсь.

Comment: @Антон, правильно ли я понимаю, что это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/327240/ верное?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему при переключении веток остаются внесенные изменения?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/327240/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что изменения не были зафиксированы (commit).